# joint and conditional density function

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, density-function

Let $f(x,y,z)$ be the joint density function. I found a reference that this joint density can be written as

$f(x,y,z) = f_1(x|y,z)f_2(y|z)f_3(z)$

I'm wondering if there are alternative forms to decompose $f(x,y,z)$. Any results would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any permutation of $x$, $y$, and $z$ in the density decomposition is also corect

Comment: If $x,y,z$ are causally related, sometimes this factorization can be truncated and written more compactly. If they are not causally related, then this expression or, as Xi'an noted, any permutation of this expression, is your option. See "Causal Inference in Statistcs: A Primer", pp. 29-30.

Comment: Many thanks for your replies!

Comment: Another question. Is $f(x,y|z)=f_1(x|y,z)f_2(y|z)=f_3(y|x,z)f_4(x|z)$ correct? I'm not confident about conditioning part...